# Bots trying to crawl non-existant movie related pages which appear to be from IMDB on my project management website

Tags: googlebot, 404, crawl-errors, visitors, semrush

In the Visitors log in cPanel I can see that googlebot, semrushbot, yandex and others are trying to access non-existant urls. The urls are related to movies & actors and appear to be on IMDB. They have never existed on my project management website stakeholdermap.com.

[image]

The visits are not showing up in my server error log or in google search console error report, but when I try to visit the non-existant page I do get my 404 page. The referring URL is blank (see the screenshot).

In the server error log I can see attempts to access wpadmin and xmlrpc which I am guessing are hacking attempts, but these wierd visits to movie related stuff don't seem like hack attempts?

I have asked support at a2hosting (my host provider) and they have told me to configure Cloudflare to block the bots, which doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: I have followed instructions from hosting provider and turned on Bot fight mode in cloudflare. I have also updated robots.txt to User-Agent: *
Disallow: /movie/
Disallow: /company/
Disallow: /actress/

Comment: Cloudflare's bot fighting mode can sometimes block Googlebot, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I will reverse that setting.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this using a WAF custom page rule in Cloudflare.

```
(http.user_agent contains "SemrushBot")
```

Looks like it is working fine.

[image]

Still don't know where SemrushBot was getting those links from.

Comment: Have you connected your site to Google Search Console? Maybe there are some weird back links that you need to disavow.

Comment: Thanks I will do that. I have read that it is a bad idea to disavow links unless you have a manual action for bad links?

Comment: If crawlers are coming to your site via those links, at a minimum I would figure out what sites are linking to those bogus links and send them a note to remove them. It is wasting your resources and theirs if they are linking to bad pages.